# How to make user control partial classes aware of controls declared in the base class?

Tags: asp.net, designer, partial-classes, base-class

Do we have to do something special to have ASP.NET partial classes aware of controls that are declared in our user control's base classes? The partial classes keep generating declarations for controls in the base class which mean the controls in the base class get hidden and are null.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The CodeFileBaseClass attribute can be applied to [@Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydy4x04a.aspx) or [@Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d19c0t4b.aspx) declarations to make the ASP.NET runtime aware of any controls declared in your base class.

MSDN describes it as follows:

> Specifies the type name of a base class for a page and its associated
>   code-behind class.
>
> This attribute is
>   optional, but when it is used the
>   CodeFile attribute must also be
>   present. Use this attribute when you
>   want to implement a shared scenario,
>   where you define common fields (and
>   optionally, associated events) in a
>   base class to reference the controls
>   declared in a Web page. Because of the
>   ASP.NET code generation model, if you
>   defined the fields in a base class
>   without using this attribute, at
>   compile time new member definitions
>   would be generated for the controls
>   declared in the Web page (within a
>   separate partial class stub), and your
>   desired scenario would not work. But
>   if you use the CodeFileBaseClass
>   attribute to associate the base class
>   with the page, and you make your
>   partial class (its name is assigned to
>   the Inherits attribute and its source
>   file is referenced by the CodeFile
>   attribute) inherit from the base
>   class, then the **fields in the base
>   class will be able to reference the
>   controls on the page after code
>   generation**.