# Show the same set of fields on different pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, layout, webforms, maintainability

I am working on a set of online forms to be filled out be new clients. The results are stored to DB and can be viewed by the user at a later time or an employee to verify data. Since many of our clients have low technical experience (or are simply obstinate and refuse to fill out the form in a timely manner), it would also be useful for employees to be able to call them and get the information over the phone, putting it into the website themselves. They may also have to make a change after the fact.

The new clients can enter the information on an "open" portion of the site, given that they have the proper invitation code, and employees manage this through the part behind a login. It's quite a bit of information, broken into three sections, and I was wondering if there was some way to have maintain the form in one place and use it across the two pages (front-end and back-end, if you will) so that if I have to make a change in one I don't have to worry about updating the other.

User Controls seem a bit too "heavy" for a fairly simple form that will appear on two pages. (No AJAX or anything fancy, just drop downs and text boxes.) It would still need to be accessible in the code-behind for the individual pages, though I wouldn't expect it to be directly accessible (using FindControl etc.) I could write a function that would programmatically create the forms, but to do so with the structured layout I'd like to use would be quite annoying.

tl;dr: Is there anything that works like `partial class`, but for the ASPX page itself without resorting to a User Control?

Comment: I have modified my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I did lot of research to solve your problem but things that I can suggest from my side

1) Use generic class

2) Strong Recommendation is to Use MVC : Its magical and have many ways to achieve your solution.

May the following links helps you:

[Reference Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/73181/ASP-NET-Web-Form-Model-with-Partial-Rendering-and)

[Reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386184/how-to-make-user-control-partial-classes-aware-of-controls-declared-in-the-base)

[Reference Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20704923/reusing-asp-net-code-in-multiple-pages)

Comment: Thank you, but the first two do not seem relevant and I already said I don't want to do User Controls for something I'll only use in two places.